# Оператор Switch или if \ else

Tags: java

Есть ли какие-то преимущества у `switch` над конструкцией (`if else + else if`) помимо визуальной наглядности

Comment: switch - это зло! Вложенные ifы - это зло! Выбирайте меньшее зло.

Comment: Свич умеет работать со строками, например. В if/else придется писать через `equals`. В `switch` можно делать кейсы слитно, тем самым обьединяя их (к примеру для 3 разных значений - одно и то же действие) - в if/else придется писать условия через `||`. В свиче можно добавить кейс `default` что лучше смотрится

Comment: @Flippy только стоит учесть, что свитч работает со строками после 7ой версии.

Answer (score 2):

Простой пример:

```
switch(a) {
  case 1:
    operation1();
  case 2:
    operation2();
    break;
...
}
```

В случае "1" будут выполнены функции operation1 и operation2, в случае "2" - только operation2.
PS: можно это описать и с помощью if else, но зачем.

Comment: точно, самый крутой момент! в `if/else` написание этой логики будет грязнее)

Answer (score 2):

Если посмотреть с точки производительности, то конструкция `switch` может быть скомпилирована в два варианта байткода с использованием:

1. TableSwitch - если варианты в операторах `case` не большие (не
   разрежены), то компилятор создаст массив с адресами на метки
   перехода.
2. LookupSwitch - если варианты разрежены, то будет создана некая
   ассоциативная таблица с значениями и метками перехода.

Из этого можно сделать вывод, что когда значения не сильно разрежены и имеют не большой диапазон, то оператор `switch` будет работать в разы быстрее, чем `if..else`, но и памяти будет потреблять больше.

Answer (score 1):

Помимо визуальных отличий из самых крутых могу рассказать про группу кейсов.

Допустим, у вас есть год (неважно откуда) и необходимо в зависимости от него делать разные вещи. К примеру, сделать одно и то же если год 1987 1900 1791

Как это выглядит в `if/else`

```
if (year == 1987 || year == 1900 || year == 1791) {}
```

В `switch`

```
switch (year) {
    case ....... 
    case 1987:
    case 1790:
    case 1791:
        //что-то там..
        break;
    case ........
}
```

Ну а вообще лучше всех - котлиновский `when` - `switch` на стероидах)